__del__ method execution order different when dealing with exception before call to del
I'm using Python 3.8.10 on Windows.
The code below prints what I expect to the console:
import gc

class Myclass():

    def my_method(self):
        raise Exception("something bad happened.")

    def __del__(self):
        print("__del__exectuted.")

print("first instance.")
my_instance = Myclass()

del my_instance
gc.collect()

print("second instance.")
my_instance_2 = Myclass()


However, if an exception is raised by the instance before calling del, it looks like the __del__ execution for that instance is delayed and only runs upon shutdown:
import gc

class Myclass():

    def my_method(self):
        raise Exception("something bad happened.")

    def __del__(self):
        print("__del__exectuted.")

print("first instance.")
my_instance = Myclass()

try:
    my_instance.my_method()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"{e}")

del my_instance
gc.collect()

print("second instance.")
my_instance_2 = Myclass()


I would expect the __del__ method to be called for the first object before "second instance." is printed, like in the first example.
Is there anything I can do to make it execute in that way?

Have you read and understood all of the notes, warnings, implementation details etc. documented for object.__del__()?

For me, on Python 3.12.3, macOS, ARM, for me this prints "first", "something", "del", "second", "del".

e is keeping the exception traceback alive, which is keeping the object itself alive.

@jasonharper On some versions of Python, anyway, apparently! If I print gc.get_referrers(my_instance) outside the exception block, there is no extra frame referring to my_instance.

@AKX It probably depends on precisely how the Exception object's traceback data is populated. If it includes the instance that the method is bound to, it will prevent it from becoming garbage.

As Object.__del__ is not guaranteed to be run, and is explicitly not called when del object is called,  if you are trying to use it for any sort of cleanup, you probably want to use weakref.finalize(self, *args) instead.  I always refer back to this video to review the topic.

@nigh_anxiety Yes, I'm trying to do some clean up when the object destroyed. The use of weakref.finalize(self, *args) is certainly better, but it does not resolve my problem as the exception object still keeps a reference of the instance. The finalizer code won't run until program exit in the same way is does with the __del__ method.

Instead of waiting until the object is deleted, would it work to turn it into a context manager?

@DanielWalker the use of a context manager is not suitable in my case.

Are you locked into using version 3.8.10?  The second code example did not reproduce the issue for me on Python 3.11.1  Based on the change logs , I think this was fixed by the updates to the gc  in Python 3.9

@nigh_anxiety, I can upgrade to 3.10 actually. I tried the second example on my machine with that version but the problem still shows with the second code example. Are you running the code on a Windows OS?

@Guett31 Yes, I'm running Python 3.11.1 on Windows 10 Home 64-bit version 22H2. I ran the script through VS Code, but that shouldn't make a difference.  I also put the entire script into a function in IDLE and had the same result

@nigh_anxiety Actually I found out that the behavior I observed with the second code example is only happening if I run the code via Visual Studio (2019). If I run the code directly on the python interpreter that Visual Studio is pointing to, I observe the expected behavior (with 3.8, 3.9  or 3.10)... It looks like Visual Studio introduces some side effects...

@Guett31  Are you running debug mode or run mode?  Maybe debug mode, or possibly some extension you have installed, is changing how the exception and object are being handled in memory
